# No mysqli_stmt_get_result() with mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

My prepared statements work just fine in MAMP with PHP 5.4 and no need to tweak php.ini. On my GoDaddy site, the same code fails with:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result().

My GoDaddy info.php shows the following as enabled:

> mysqli Client API library version 5.5.45
>
> mysqlnd: mysqlnd 5.0.10
> Loadedplugins:mysqlnd,example,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
> API Extensions: none

GoDaddy says their PHP is working just fine, although I doubt they tested for this function. They claim it must be a code error, which strikes me as inconsistent with both, the nature of the error and the fact the code works in MAMP.

What's my next step?

Comment: You're sure MySQLND is installed? Is the Godaddy server Linux?

Comment: @Machavity He showed the `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but I've seen some crazy installs where it will list MySQLND but not use it. Just trying to rule that out

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for how he should determine whether it's installed, other than the output of phpinfo?

Comment: All I have is the phpinfo output. Inside my cPanel account is a page where I can select a number of options and mysql, mysqli and mysqlnd are pre-selected. Could the Client API library version have preference; I'm not sure there's a way for me to turn it off. Yes, it's Linux.

Comment: Would it help if I showed the query, It's pretty standard and, as I say, it works fine in MAMP.

Comment: The only difference between the MAMP phpinfo and the GoDaddy phpinfo is under mysqlnd   API Extensions where GoDaddy has none and MAMP has   mysqli,pdo_mysql,mysql

Comment: So it's a problem.

Comment: The problem exists not only on my site but also a client's site on GoDaddy and, I now discover, on a second client's site on a different host. I will abandon this approach and use mysqli_stmt_bind_result() and mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Less convenient for updating code but more certain of results and I don't have to negotiate with server hosts.

Answer (score 6):

Enable nd_mysqli in php extensions and disable mysqli

Comment: This worked. Apparently those two cannot be enabled at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel of go daddy 
Then select php and then select nd_mysqli and save

It must work under any circumstances